# How to create External Table without specifying columns in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a folder containing files in parquet format. I used crawler to create table defined in Glue Data Catalog which counted to 2500+ columns. I want to create External Table on top of it in redshift.
But all the articles that I read have mentioned the columns explicitly.
Is there any way so that the Table reads schema directly from the table in data catalog and I don't have to feed it separately?

Comment: You likely have a bigger problem.  Redshift tables are limited to 1,600 columns.

Comment: Hi @BillWeiner, is there a way such that I can use the table in Glue catalog to create the external table? I am currently able to use athena to execute the queries. Apart from that, I can reduce the columns to 1500-1600 since most of the columns are of no use.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [external schema](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-schemas.html)  in Redshift which is based on a data catalog. This way, you will see all tables in the data catalog without creating them in Redshift.

```
create external schema spectrum_schema
from data catalog 
database 'spectrum_db' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MySpectrumRole'
create external database if not exists;
```

In the above example from the documentation, `spectrum_db` is the name of your data catalog.